# Create new file in S3 using AWS lambda function

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a requirement that my lambda functions creates a new CSV file and uploads it after writing to it . I am using Python boto3 for this purpose

```
with open('mycsv.csv', 'w', newline ='') as f:
     thewriter = csv.writer(f)
     thewriter.writerow(['col1','col2','col3'])
     s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3_client.upload_file('/tmp/' + mycsv.csv, 'my-bucket', 'myfoleder/'+mycsv.csv)
```

Note that the file 'mycsv.csv' does not exist already and I want to be able to create it on the fly as part of the lambda function. Is this even possible? I get the following error when the lambda is triggered

```
[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'mycsv.csv'
```

Answer (score 2):

On lambda, the filesystem is mostly readonly with the exception of the `/tmp` directory. When you open the file for writing it needs to go to `/tmp/mycsv.csv`:

```
with open('/tmp/mycsv.csv', 'w', newline ='') as f:
     thewriter = csv.writer(f)
     thewriter.writerow(['col1','col2','col3'])
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3_client.upload_file('/tmp/mycsv.csv', 'my-bucket', 'myfolder/mycsv.csv')
```

You might also consider using Python's [tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), which will automatically write to `/tmp` and will delete the file once you exit the context manager block.

Comment: Careful... The upload should be _outside_ of the `with`, otherwise the file is still open.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! If the upload is inside with, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the intermediate file and process your data completely in memory. This has the advantage of being faster and allows you to handle larger data. Currently, [Lambda offers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) only 512 MB of disk space in `/tmp`, but up to 3 GB of memory.

```
import csv
import io

buffer = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(buffer)
writer.writerow(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

buffer.seek(0)
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.upload_fileobj(buffer, 'my-bucket', 'my-folder/mycsv.csv')
```

Consider also compressing your CSV files. This will result in faster and cheaper transfers to/from S3.

```
import gzip

# ...

buffer.seek(0)
compressed = io.BytesIO(gzip.compress(buffer.getvalue().encode('utf-8')))

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.upload_fileobj(compressed, 'my-bucket', 'my-folder/mycsv.csv.gz')
```